# Unexpected Operator .sh file

Tags: bash

Why wont this code run?
It is meant to allow the user to input a number into the script in a loop until the user enters a -1 then the script should terminate
However I keep getting this error:

```
-ne: unexpected operator
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

condition= 0

while [ $condition -ne -1 ]
do
        echo $condition
        read condition
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the space after the `condition=` and the `0`. As spaces are the natural token separator of bash, you have to be very careful where you put spaces. In this case, the space separates a list of initialized variables (in this case with an empty value) of the supposed program (`0`).

Answer (score 2):

The space after =. Remove it .

Answer (score 2):

Well, many already gave you the answers, nevertheless, just see this one if you need it (is just another way, a little more verbose).

```
#!/bin/sh

while read condition; do
 case "$condition" in
   -1) printf "GOOD BYE!\n"; break ;;
    *) printf "AGAIN, PUT A NUMBER!" ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a semicolon `;` after the closing bracket.

Comment: A semicolon is necessary only if the `do` appears on the same line as the `while`.